# How to wait until forM_ finishes, when using TVar?

Tags: multithreading, haskell, concurrency, stm, tvar

I'm writing a function, where I process a list using `forM_`, and append the result to a `TVar` list:

```
import Control.Concurrent.STM
import Control.Concurrent.STM.TVar
import Control.Concurrent (forkIO)
import Control.Monad (forM_)

insert :: a -> [a] -> [a]
insert = (:) -- stub

my_func_c :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> IO [a]
my_func_c my_function arr = do

    res_var <- atomically $ newTVar ([]::[a])

    forkIO $ forM_ arr $ \x -> atomically $ do
        let y = id $! my_function x
        modifyTVar res_var (insert y)

    atomically $ readTVar res_var
```

The result is always empty, if I compile it with `-threaded`. How is it possible to wait for the threads to finish? I can not use `MVar` or `Async`. I have to solve this problem using `TVar`, or other data structures which are based on `TVar`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiomatic solution would be to use [`TMVar`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm/docs/Control-Concurrent-STM-TMVar.html)s:

```
my_func_c :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> IO [a]
my_func_c my_function arr = do
    res_var <- atomically $ newTVar []
    finished <- atomically $ newEmptyTMVar

    forkIO $ do
        forM_ arr $ \x -> atomically $ do
            let y = id $! my_function x
            modifyTVar res_var (insert y)
        atomically $ putTMVar finished ()

    atomically $ takeTMVar finished >> readTVar res_var
```

but if you are really only allowed to use `TVar`s, you can simulate a `TMVar ()` with a `TVar Bool`:

```
my_func_c :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> IO [a]
my_func_c my_function arr = do
    res_var <- atomically $ newTVar []
    finished <- atomically $ newTVar False

    forkIO $ do
        forM_ arr $ \x -> atomically $ do
            let y = id $! my_function x
            modifyTVar res_var (insert y)
        atomically $ writeTVar finished True

    atomically $ waitTVar finished >> readTVar res_var

waitTVar :: TVar Bool -> STM ()
waitTVar tv = do
    finished <- readTVar tv
    unless finished retry
```

Under the hood, [`TMVar a` is just a `TVar (Maybe a)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-2.4.4.1/docs/src/Control.Concurrent.STM.TMVar.html#TMVar) (so `TMVar ()` ~ `TVar (Maybe ())` ~ `TVar Bool`) with [`takeTMVar` doing a `readTVar` and a `retry`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-2.4.4.1/docs/src/Control.Concurrent.STM.TMVar.html#takeTMVar), so the above two solutions are operationally completely equivalent.

Comment: Why isn't `writeTVar finished True` required in each forM_ function call? Why is it outside `forM_`?

Comment: The point is that you `writeTVar finished True` / `putTMVar finished ` when you are fully finished, i.e. after *all* results have been computed. Note that this would also work if inside `forM_`, all elements are processed in a separate thread (which is what I assume you will want to do in your real app)